# Null pointerException while getting Primary Key(primitive datatype) in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I'm getting Null Pointer Exception while retrieving Primary Key or Id of an Entity in Hibernate result query.

My Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sample")
public class ccy{

@Id
@column(name = "S_ID")
private long id;

 2nd varibale and so on
```

when i write hibernate query to retrieve it causes Null pointer exception, my select query is:

```
long ID = 0;
String HQL = "select id from sample";
Query query = session.createQuery(HQL);
ID = (Long)query.uniqueResult(); //getting NullPointerException in this line
 return ID;
```

Any suggestions to avoid this exception? I'm stuck here. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: the ID you are getting, does not exist

Comment: Yes correct, but why Null Pointer Exception? It should return null to ID right?